# How to use LINQ to select into an object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have data that looks like so:

```
UserId   |  SongId
--------   --------
1          1
1          4
1          12
2          95
```

I also have the following class:

```
class SongsForUser
{
    public int User;
    public List<int> Songs;
}
```

What I would like to do is use LINQ to select from my data to create a collection of SongsForUser objects.  Below is what I have come up with so far:

```
var userCombos = songs.UserSongs.Select(x => new SongsForUser() { User = x.UserId, 
                                                                  Songs = /*What goes here?*/ });
```

How would I go about populating my `Songs` List?

So the result should be two SongsForUser objects.  For user `1` it would have 3 items in the `Songs` list.  For user `2` it would have 1 item in the `Songs` list.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
songs.UserSongs.GroupBy(x => x.User).Select(g => new SongsForUser() 
{ 
    User = g.Key,
    Songs = g.Select(s => s.SongId).ToList()
});
```

Comment: Why select the song ID only within the projection, rather than as part of the grouping?

Comment: This is throwing an error on the `ToList` portion.  I believe it may be because this is Linq to Entities.  Error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ToList[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @AbeMiessler make sure you have `using System.Linq` up top.

Comment: Nice. Came up with a similar solution. +1

Comment: @AbeMiessler: It would have been nice if you'd mentioned LINQ to Entities to start with...

Comment: Yes, I realize that was a mistake.  I apologize.

Comment: @AbeMiessler: If the `ToList` is failing for you, see the edit to my answer for a potential workaround.

Answer (score 22):

I suspect you want:

```
var songsByUser = songs.UserSongs
                       .GroupBy(song => song.UserId, song => song.SongId)
                       .Select(g => new SongsForUser { User = g.Key,
                                                       Songs = g.ToList() });
```

To explain, after the `GroupBy` you'll have a bunch of groups, where the key of each group is the user ID, and the values within the group are the song IDs:

```
Key = 1, Values = 1, 4, 12
Key = 2, Value = 95
```

Then you're just converting that into your `SongsForUser` type. Note that you don't need to explicitly include the `()` when calling the constructor in an object initializer - it's implicit unless you need to specify constructor arguments.

You *could* do this all in one `GroupBy` call, by the way:

```
var songsByUser = songs.UserSongs
         .GroupBy(song => song.UserId, song => song.SongId,
                  (user, ids) => new SongsForUser { User = user,
                                                    Songs = ids.ToList() });
```

Personally I usually find a separate `Select` call to be more readable.

You can also do all of this with a query expression:

```
var songsByUser = from song in songs.UserSongs
                  group song.SongId by song.UserId into g
                  select new SongsForUser { User = g.Key, Songs = g.ToList() };
```

EDIT: The above is "provider-neutral" but it sounds like it's not working with LINQ to Entities. You *may* be able to get it to work like this:

```
var songsByUser = songs.UserSongs
                       .GroupBy(song => song.UserId, song => song.SongId)
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(g => new SongsForUser { User = g.Key,
                                                       Songs = g.ToList() });
```

The `AsEnumerable` call will force the grouping to be done in the database, but the final projection (including the `ToList` call) to be done locally. You should check the generated SQL for efficiency though.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the following:

```
public class SongsForUser
{
    public int UserId;
    public List<int> Songs;
}
```

Then a function like this one here will do. The list is just there to have
some data to test with.

```
    public void Group()
    {
        List<Tuple<int, int>> SongRelations = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

        SongRelations.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
        SongRelations.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 4));
        SongRelations.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 12));
        SongRelations.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(2, 95));

        var list = SongRelations.GroupBy(s => s.Item1)
                                .Select(r => new SongsForUser()
                                {
                                    UserId = r.Key,
                                    Songs = r.Select(t => t.Item2).ToList(),
                                });
    }
```

`list` contains 2 items of type SongsForUser afterwards.
One with user 1 and a list of songs containing 1, 4 and 12
and one with user 2 and a list of songs containing 95.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form you can just:

```
List<MapPoint> points = db.PropertyResearches.Where(a => a.deptId == 66).Select(x => new MapPoint { property = x.notes.Substring(0, 10), latitude = x.lat, longitude = x.@long }).ToList();
```